# Aligning text within an anchor

Tags: html, css, text, anchor

I have a problem. I'm trying to get the text inside of an anchor tag to align at the bottom of the image inside of the anchor tag.

Here is how it shows now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKeey.jpg

Here is how it's supposed to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDq64.jpg

I've tried everything with the vertical-align property in CSS but it's not working.

Any help?

Here is the request HTML and CSS code

```
#facebook { float: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 10px; height: 22px; }

#facebook a { font-family: Gerogia; font-size: 18px; font-style: italic; color: #808080;      text-decoration: none; }

#facebook a img, #facebook a span {
vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

<div id="facebook"> <!-- Start facebook -->
<a href="#">
    <span>Like Us&nbsp;</span><img src="images/facebook.jpg" alt="Facebook" />
</a>
</div> <!-- End facebook -->
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to post your html/css. The text should be bottom aligned by default. http://jsfiddle.net/3PxUn/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the line-height of the anchor tag equal to the font-size of the "span" text. Also, vertical-align: bottom.

**EDIT:**

Try using "vertical-align: bottom" instead of "vertical-align: text-bottom". [Check out these options from w3schools on the "vertical-align" spec.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) <sub>(not associated with the w3c)</sub>

**EDIT:**

Make the line-height of your "span" text equal to its font-size. I think the line-height is actually larger, and that's why you're seeing it not PERFECTLY aligned at the bottom...because the entire shape / cell of the text is the line-height and NOT the font-size. To normalize, make it equal like this (assuming you've kept a font-size of 18px):

```
#facebook a span {
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

[A page going into some detail explaining this is here.](http://www.slideshare.net/maxdesign/line-height)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great article by Chris Coyier explaining what is going on with this situation: http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/